# Laravel Eloquent hasMany and BelongsToMany not returning using with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do a single query to get back an `order` and the `card` to charge, but getting an error.

Card model:

```
class Card extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}
```

Order model:

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Card');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
    }
}
```

What I am trying to get back:

```
$order = Order::with('card')->find($id);
```

This obviously doesn't work and I have tried several combos. I think the issue is with my models/relationships.

Any idea how I can get back the order with the card/token details?

DB info: Each order can have only one `card_id` and each card can be in many orders. There is no `order_id` in the card.

Orders table basically:

```
id | card_id
```

Cards table:

```
id | token
```

Trying to get the `token` col to return with the `Order`.

Comment: Can you provide a description of the database schema.

Comment: @LoganBailey  Added. Very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Order` model, you need to change this:

```
public function card()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Card');
}
```

to this:

```
public function card()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Card');
}
```

The reason is that you are defining the inverse of the `hasMany` relationship. With the `belongsTo` relationship, Eloquent will look for a `card_id` column on the `orders` table.

Comment: Good grief. That was it. Thanks!